# How to have multiple filter on an JQuery Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, filter

I currently have some code to filter an array based on price range using a slider. I need to be able to add checkboxes for various sizes and colors so that I can also filter using their values. This is the code I have so far but am unsure how to implement checkboxes so that I have have multiple ways of filtering the array.

```
//this is the main generated array
    var product = [{"price":"200","color":"red","size":"small"},
                   {"price":"250","color":"brown","size":"medium"},
                   {"price":"300","color":"red","size":"large"}];

// array to display filtered array
    var filteredProducts = [];  
    var key = 0;

//start of price range filter
    if(!minPrice && !maxPrice){
       filteredProducts = products;
    } else{
       $.each(products, function(i, object) {   
           var curentPrice = parseFloat(object.price); 
           var priceMinOk = true;
           var priceMaxOk = true;
       // filter results match the price range
           if(maxPrice || minPrice){
              if(maxPrice && maxPrice<curentPrice){
                 priceMaxOk = false;
              }
              if(minPrice && minPrice>curentPrice){
                 priceMinOk = false;
              }
           }  
       //  loop over list and get only related to new array
           if( priceMinOk && priceMaxOk ){  
              filteredProducts[key] = object;                  
              key++;
           }  
       });
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help"

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ltbmedia/86pEn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep) instead of `$.each`, and structure the code like this:

```
var products = [ /* ... */ ],
    predicates = [
        function predicate1(obj) { /* ... */ },
        function predicate2(obj) { /* ... */ },
        // ... ,
        function predicateN(obj) { /* ... */ }
    ],
    filteredProducts;

filteredProducts = $.grep(products, function (element, index)
{
    for (var i=0; i<predicates.length; i++)
    {
        if (!predicates[i](element)) return false;
    }

    return true;
});
```

---

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Rsbcu/

---

More complex example: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/vZzjM/

You might notice that you're *still* getting an empty array back, but this actually makes sense. Given the criteria you've specified (`minPrice = 201, maxPrice = 301, color = red or green, size = small`) **there are no matching array elements.**

Loosen up the price criteria just a *tiny* bit and you'll see that everything works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/MQ8Mc/

Comment: Thanks Matt, I am assuming that each 'function predicate1(obj) { /* ... */ } is for each filter element (ie size), is that right?

Comment: That's right. Each predicate would test for a separate condition on each element. In the example code in your question, you'd use two predicates, one to test the min price condition, and one to test the max price condition. BTW, a predicate is a function which returns a boolean value.

Comment: Thanks again but not sure I quite know what you mean. How would a predictate function test for a specific element value, sorry, been banging my head against the wall all day on this one!

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for that and I think it cleared things up a bit! Would it be possible for you to look at my edit and see where I am going wrong, getting an empty array now and can I use multiple checkboxes with this method? Thanks...

Comment: For starters, you're trying to `parseFloat` colors and sizes, which just won't work...

Comment: You also have not written the predicates to handle multiple checked values.

Comment: Hey Matt, that's great, thanks for all your help and patience, really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey Matt, wondering if you could help one last time or guide me. What you did works great, but I now need it to also work backwards.See my edit for example, but the idea is if only one designer was checked and the array only had one object (small,brown) then all the other size and color checboxes would automatically uncheck, and the same idea for the price range.